# Regex pattern returns more matches than expected

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex in javascript should return every word found betweend brackets [].

```
/\[(\w|\d|\s)*\]/
```

However it also returns a second result which doesn't match the regex. In regex testers I only get the match '[id]'. However in the example it also matches 'd' which is a false result.

I can't seem to see why.

```js
const title = "Detail boeking [id]"
const titleParameters = title.match(/\[(\w|\d|\s)*\]/);

$.each(titleParameters, function(e, v) {
  $('#test').append("matched value:" + v + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

See also jsfiddle for a working example of this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2vxsjgy6/.

Comment: It is matching only `[id]` but since you've a capture group as well, it is returning 2 elements in resulting array of `match`, better to use `/\[[\w\s]*\]/)` or see: https://jsfiddle.net/qczgum4x/

Comment: What's the point of the capture group? `(`

Comment: Use `/\[[\w\s]*]/` or `/\[[^\][]*]/`

Comment: Wouldn't have been better to write an answer rather than close the question and answer in the comments ?

Comment: IMHO writing an answer in the comments is pure politeness, there is no real reason to answer a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Change your regexp to `/\[[\w|\d|\s]*\]/` (square brackets)